# Here Maps Telematics TOLLS API - specifying roundtrip

Tags: here-api

I am working with Telematics API https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json to calculate the toll costs. Can I please ask if anyone has used or aware if there is a special parameter to denote one way or round trip. I am using waypoints to represent round trip as in waypoint0 = source, waypoint1=destination, waypoint2=source to represent my round trip. The values returned are high compared to the ones indicated by local teams who use that toll regularly
As example 59.9133301,10.7389701 -> 60.6244351,11.3831208 -> 59.9133301,10.7389701 shows 816 NOK but real value is only 660. A one way from 59.9133301,10.7389701 -> 60.6244351,11.3831208 shows 340 NOK which may be right

So is there another way on API to ask for toll cost combined for both directions?

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Please share you complete request. I am unable to reproduce the issue.

You can refer to these example request:

1. Round Trip request :

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?jsonAttributes=41&waypoint0=59.9133301,10.7389701&detail=1&waypoint1=60.6244351,11.3831208&waypoint2=59.9133301,10.7389701&maneuverAttributes=none&linkAttributes=none,sh&legAttributes=none,li&currency=NOK&departure=&tollVehicleType=2&trailerType=0&trailersCount=0&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=0&hybrid=0&emissionType=5&fuelType=petrol&height=1.67m&trailerHeight=0&vehicleWeight=1739&limitedWeight=1.739t&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=2&tiresCount=4&commercial=0&heightAbove1stAxle=1m&width=1.8m&length=4.41m&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&rollups=none,country;tollsys&&tollPass=transponder&apikey=<apikey>&jsoncallback=parseRouting
```

- Result TollCost: 244.8

2. One way request :

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?jsonAttributes=41&waypoint0=59.9133301,10.7389701&detail=1&waypoint1=60.62544,11.37563&maneuverAttributes=none&linkAttributes=none,sh&legAttributes=none,li&currency=NOK&departure=&tollVehicleType=2&trailerType=0&trailersCount=0&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=0&hybrid=0&emissionType=5&fuelType=petrol&height=1.67m&trailerHeight=0&vehicleWeight=1739&limitedWeight=1.739t&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=2&tiresCount=4&commercial=0&heightAbove1stAxle=1m&width=1.8m&length=4.41m&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&rollups=none,country;tollsys&&tollPass=transponder&apikey=<apikey>&jsoncallback=parseRoutingResponse
```

- Result toll cost 113.6

3. Back to source

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?jsonAttributes=41&detail=1&waypoint0=60.6244351,11.3831208&waypoint1=59.9133301,10.7389701&maneuverAttributes=none&linkAttributes=none,sh&legAttributes=none,li&currency=NOK&departure=&tollVehicleType=2&trailerType=0&trailersCount=0&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=0&hybrid=0&emissionType=5&fuelType=petrol&height=1.67m&trailerHeight=0&vehicleWeight=1739&limitedWeight=1.739t&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=2&tiresCount=4&commercial=0&heightAbove1stAxle=1m&width=1.8m&length=4.41m&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&rollups=none,country;tollsys&&tollPass=transponder&apikey=<apikey>&jsoncallback=parseRoutingResponse
```

- Result tollcost 131.2

Toll cost of route (1) = toll cost of route (2+3)